# GKE Managed Certificate not serving over HTTPS

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to spin up a Kubernetes cluster that I can access securely and can't seem to get that last part. I am following this tutorial: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/managed-certs

Here are the `.yaml` files i'm using for my Ingress, Nodeport and ManagedCertificate

```
apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1beta1
kind: ManagedCertificate
metadata:
  name: client-v1-cert
spec:
  domains:
    - api.mydomain.com
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: client-nodeport-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: myApp
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 3000
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: api-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: api-v1
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: client-v1-cert
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: client-nodeport-service
    servicePort: 80
```

No errors that I can see in the GCP console. i can also access my API from `http://api.mydomain.com/`, but it won't work when I try `https`, just not https. Been banging my head on this for a few days and just wondering if there's some little thing i'm missing.

--- UPDATE ---

Output of `kubectl describe managedcertificate`

```
Name:         client-v1-cert
Namespace:    default
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
API Version:  networking.gke.io/v1beta1
Kind:         ManagedCertificate
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2019-07-01T17:42:43Z
  Generation:          3
  Resource Version:    1136504
  Self Link:           /apis/networking.gke.io/v1beta1/namespaces/default/managedcer
tificates/client-v1-cert
  UID:                 b9b7bec1-9c27-33c9-a309-42284a800179
Spec:
  Domains:
    api.mydomain.com
Status:
  Certificate Name:    mcrt-286cdab3-b995-40cc-9b3a-28439285e694
  Certificate Status:  Active
  Domain Status:
    Domain:     api.mydomain.com
    Status:     Active
  Expire Time:  2019-09-29T09:55:12.000-07:00
Events:         <none>
```

Comment: What does `kubectl describe managedcertificate` output. Edit your question with details.

Comment: You have two domains (api.honeycomb.tools and api.mydomain.com). Is this just an edit mask or a real mistake? The output says your certificate is active. Go to MxTooolbox https://mxtoolbox.com/dnscheck.aspx and make sure that you don't have any DNS issues.

Comment: That is merely my attempt to conceal my domain lol. I missed one of them i guess. should I have 0 errors when i check my domain with this site? There are a few errors that I can try to fix. Is it likely that my DNS is the problem? It does seem like everything on the Kubernetes side of things is in the right place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out a solution to this problem. I ended up going into my GCP console, locating the load balancer associated with the Ingress, and then I noticed that there was only one frontend protocol, and it was HTTP serving over port 80. So I manually added another frontend protocol for HTTPS, selected the managed certificate from the list, and waited about 5 minutes and everything worked.

I have no idea why my `ingress.yaml` didn't do that automatically though. So though the problem is fixed if there is anyone out there who knows what I would love to know.

Comment: I have experienced this too. It does not seem to work the way the documentation says.

Comment: how would configure your ManagedCertificate , it's domains in case you have an mobile app ?